# How can I transfer blocked numbers/phrases?

Tags: samsung, call-history, call-screening

I have many blocked numbers/message phrases list on my Samsung S8 Plus phone. Never rooted it and it has still official rom. I will use with the same rom. I will just format it but I don't want to bother with
insert the numbers one by one after formatting.

**So, is there a way to restore numbers/phrases with a JSON/XML file or something else on stock rom?**

[image: Block Numbers]

[image: Block Phrases]

Comment: This seem to be a feature of the Samsung Messages app (com.samsung.android.messaging). Unfortunately adb backup is disabled for this app.

Comment: @Robert Yes I don't want to use another app as most of them are not stable . I'm using old rom just for similar reasons. Thanks anyway

Comment: One of the problems with many of the stock Samsung apps is that they have no export functionality.

Comment: For now, I have found this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myblocked). It is exporting numbers as json format at least. But it does not have any action for message phrases

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket You have right. I used many custom roms in the past to export on my old phone. Samsung's some apps supports to transfer another datas but they should think to export for different formats also